# Typescript Angular Component, colon vs. equals

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm experimenting with the angular tutorial at [https://angular.io](http://angular.io).

After some editing, the code ended up like this:

```
@Component({
   ...
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes = HEROES;  // here 1
  selectedHero: Hero;  // here 2

  ...
}
```

There's an assignment with an equal sign followed by what looks like an object initialization.

I don't understand the difference between "here 1" and "here 2".  I'm confused by the syntaxes of what appear to be two assignments.  What's above is the only form that compiles.  Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one you are **`initializing`** heroes by **`assigning`** the array **`HEROES`**, the later one you are just declaring the type of selectedHero to be of type **`Hero`**

```
heroes = HEROES;     //Assigning the value
selectedHero: Hero;  //here 2 //Declaring the variable of type
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's day 0 of Typescript for me.  Threw me for a sec.  :-)

Comment: Mark if the answer helped

Comment: Should there have been a 'var' or 'let' before the selectedHero for clarity?

Comment: No need to have one while declaraing

Answer (score 1):

**heroes = HEROES;**  // here 1 is ***assigning value 'HEROES'*** to the class variable heroes.

**selectedHero: Hero;**  // here 2 is making sure that the class variable ***'selectedHero' is of type 'Hero'***. This is useful in case of typescript as it will show error(if used with IDE) when a value different from Hero is assigned to variable 'selectedHero'.

This is typescript, and it transpiles. But when in production mode its all compiled in javascript with used features like **prototyping**. For more javascript compilation you can search the google.